# What is a appropriate way to compare two objects with hashsets?

Tags: java, hashset

I have a person class which has a name and a list of friends in HashSet.

I want to override an `equals` method for this Person class. Below is what I have written so far.

But I am unsure about this because, I know that HashSet does not necessarily have to be in order, and I also heard that I have to override HashCode method.

What modifications should I make in below codes to correctly implement equals method?

```
public boolean equals(Note target){
    if(this.name==target.getName() && this.friends == target.getFriends()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public HashSet<Person> getFriends(){
    return this.friends;
}
```

**edit**

```
//override hashCode()
public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashCode() + friends.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you use the correct method signature if you intend to [override](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) equals (which you should), i.e. `public boolean equals(Object obj)` and then check for correct type, etc. By using `Note` as a parameter, you will [overload](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) equals, which is something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `==` operator is definitely wrong for the `HashSet` and `name`. If you want to compare objects in java use the equals method. The `==` operator compares the internal object IDs managed by the JVM. The contract for `HashSet`'s `equals` method is document in [`AbstractSet.equals()`](http://ownload.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){

    if (o instanceof Note) {
        Note target = (Note) o;
        if(this.name.equals(target.getName()) && this.friends.equals(target.getFriends())){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You may want to check for `null`'s as well, maybe `name` and `fiends` can be null.

A lot has been writen regarding `equals` and `hashCode`. The best way is to look into the JavaDoc for [`lava.lang.Object.equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: I got a comment in my question that I have to receive `(Object target)` as a parameter. Will it be fine if I still use `(Note target)` as a input parameter?

Comment: Ups, I missed that, @matsev is right, I updated the answer. I also added `@Override` annotation which enforces a compiler check to verify that `Note` overrides a method defined in one of its subclasses (in this case `java.lang.Object`).

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your help. I also have to override the `hashCode()` method, right? I have added hashCode in the question above by editing the question. Can you skim through it if that is okay?

Comment: No prob. hashCode looks fine. it's important to understand that a hash code must _not_ guarantee uniqueness. It is a helper for Java's built-in hash functionality. So you should design your hashCode methods in a way that avoids hash collision wherever possible: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Comment: Hey.. I found a problem here. If one of elements in this.friends has added `this` in its friends list, there is a recursion getting hashCode. (if 2 friends are in mutual friends) Does that mean I should not include friends in `hashCode` return?

Comment: If Note's name is unique, returning only `name`'s hash code should be enough. Could could also include the `size` of `friends`.

Answer (score 1):

The way you currently have your `equals(Note)` method setup, it will (almost) never return `true`.  When working with `String` objects you should always use `equals(String)`, never `==`.

I would create my `Note.equals(Note)` method something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(obj instanceof Note) {
        Note target = (Note) obj;
        if(name.equals(target.name) && friends.containsAll(target.friends)
              && friends.size() == target.friends.size()){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You will notice that the `equals(Note)` method I provided above also doesn't do `friends.equals(target.getFriends())`.  This is because you are comparing the containing `HashSet`, and not the contents of the `HashSet`.

Finally, if you want your `Note` class to hash properly, you will also need to override your `hashCode()` method.  You can read more about this contract in the description of the [`hashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) method in the [`Object`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) documentation.

```
public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashCode() + friends.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: What if I have more than 1 `hashSet` (other than friends) used in a class variables? Do I just add them up in the `hashCode()` statement as well?

Comment: If they are going to be used to calculate your `equals(Object)` method, then they should also be used in your `hashCode()` calculation.

Comment: Thank you for your hashCode implementation. It gave me a lot of helps